# Creating another Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I'm doing too much work on the main thread, and so I want to learn how to run some things on other threads. But I'm having difficulties understanding how threads work.

From what I've gathered, you can no longer stop or cancel a thread, and the way that I need it to work is that, if Button A is clicked, do the function, if Button B is clicked, stop as to not use resources.

Here's where I stand:

```
> //Inside OnCreate

Thread newthread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override

            public void run(){

                while(bool) {
                    ...
                }
                    ...
            }
        });
        newthread.start();


Button A Listener(){
bool = true;
}

Button A Listener(){
bool = false;
}
```

when I first start the thread it runs, but after changing bool to false, and back to true it doesn't.

putting return at the end destroys the thread, but calling start again isn't allowed.

I've tried putting 2 while loops, but it still doesn't switch between the loops.

Is there even a reason to use interrupt? and how would it be implemented?

**What I need is to create another thread, have it keep doing something until I click button A, then resume when I click on Button B, that's all.**

Answer (score 0):

> but calling start again isn't allowed.

Not sure why don't you can not call start again, but I think it's good solution. Base on your requirement tries this code put inside `run`

```
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          try {
              if (loop) {
                  ...
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              return;
          }
      }
```

Why we need to check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` because when your `Activity` destroy you should call `newthread.interrupt()` to release your `Thread` because it can be leak memory.

Comment: 1. I get error on catch, "not in the try block", also I don't need to interrupt the thread? wouldn't keeping the thread running (even if it's not doing anything) consume processing?

Comment: "Exception is never thrown in the corresponding try block", it does not let me run

Comment: If you don't need interupt simplify you can use while(true) { if (loop) { ... } }

Comment: ""Exception is never thrown in the corresponding try block" seems that you're not using the correct catch block, try generify with "Exception e". or if you using above code, try to put the while loop INSIDE try block. Edit: "What I need is to create another thread, have it keep doing something until I click button A, then resume when I click on Button B, that's all." maybe you need read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/